# Function unwilling to calculate results, instead assigns/leaves variables NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not able to make function trajgen() to calculate x and y and after three days put in trying I still can't find the solution. The whole program is over 200 lines so I'll cross my fingers you to find something false in the following 'problematic' function. :)
Take a look...

```
function trajgen(){
    $(".reddot").remove();
    x=xo;
    y=yo;
    $(".reddot").css({"top": y, "left": x});
    isin=true;

    while(isin==true){
        x = xo + v0*Math.cos(angle)*time;
        y = yo + v0*Math.sin(angle)*time - 0.5*g*Math.pow(time,2);
        alert("x= "+x);
        alert("y= "+y);

        $("#frames").append('<div class = "reddot" style = "top: '+ y + 'px; left: '+ x +'px;"><img src="red.png" height="10" width="10"></div>');
        time+=1;
        isin=inchecker();
    }
    return;
}

function inchecker(){
    if(y<Dy||y>Ay||x<Dx||x>Bx){ 
        isin = false;
        return isin;
    }
    isin = true;
    return isin;
}
```

Now, when I alert x and y this thing returns me NaNs (i know what it means), for the both coordinates. Another interesting aspect is that function inchecker doesn't stop the buggy reddot appending after they get out of the div I'm using as a element where to draw my trajectory. Instead of getting parabolic arc I get infinitely vertically clonning/appending red points. All other variables work properly, x, y, xo, yo, speed, time... and so on are globals. Xo and yo I get as (0;0) from where to launch the projectile and I found out that all other variables work well, the only problem is with those x and y which I haven't used anywhere else so far. I assigned them with zeros but by now this doesn't change the unwillingness of my script to calculate x and y. #frames is the div where all those things happen. Please, help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: ok :) 



     var time=0.5, v0;

    angle = (angle*Math.PI)/180;  
    v0 = speed;

speed, g and angle are globals, as v0. I change angle to rads due to my function. Xo and Yo I get on click and there is another function which does that and which invokes trajgen() each time a new (0;0) a.k.a.(xo,yo) is being inputed, by click.

Comment: You get xo and yo via user input? How? Via jQuery? Have you checked if they are number types before using them?

Comment: No, it's generally JS and I swear you, it does it's job perfectly. 
 function saveOO(e){
    var savedOO;
    xo = e.clientX;
    yo = e.clientY;
    savedOO = "The(0;0) = " + "(" + xo +"," + " " + yo + ")";
    document.getElementById("saved").innerHTML = savedOO;
    document.getElementById("point").style.top=yo + 'px';
    document.getElementById("point").style.left=xo + 'px';
    trajgen();
   } 
no problems with it, I've checker several times if this gets the right stuff and it does it, also triggers trajgen() and I also discovered that trajgen()  is successfully invoked but something...

Comment: console.log(xo, yo, angle) is what?

Comment: ...is wrong with the positioning of those reddots which I hope is caused by not calculating those x and y which later are used exactly with this purpose

Comment: [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/vq0960.png[/IMG] 

My element inspector is totally clear of errors, it gives none... It should be something logically mistaken. Now I'll assign 0-os to each variable and see what will happen bu...

Comment: An the result is... absolutely the same :/ :)

Comment: Op, when it starts popping like crazy those red dots vertically and I try to adjust the sliders it gave me this : Uncaught error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'value'

Comment: Looking at your code are `x` and `y` supposed to be global variables? also this `x=xo; y=yo;` I cant see where `xo` and `yo` are defined? Are they global variables also? If your alerts are returning you `NaNs` have you tried `console.log(typeof(x))` to see if they are numbers and not strings?

Comment: Ok, so I've been trying to find out what the... causes this bug, by using debugger, as dwoz proposed. Now, it is constantly getting NaNs for x and y but the reason is that while computing them I use a formula using var angle. Look at this line -> angle1 = (angle*3.14)/180;  Now i changed Math.cos(angle) to Math.cos(angle1) the next line, also I did the same way. And debugger says the following: initially angle is undefined, when I move the slider it assigns a value to 'angle', angle1 is   NaN and when I write angle1=(angle*3.14)/180 angle1 remains NaN BUT console.log(of the same expression)..

Comment: returns a calucated result a.k.a. a Number, a float type one. So far, this angle1 was initialized like var angle1; When I made it global it was still NaN. When I made it global and directly gave it value 120 IT TOOK IT, that made me try declaring angle1 by meanwhile giving it the value of the expression - again NaN. What's even more weird I've implied that in an experiment I made I set angle1=120 and it showed 120. After that i deleted this line of code angle1=120, and under it I left one small alert("angle1= "+ angle1), I refreshed the webpage and from debugger I got angle1 = 120 when don't

Comment: Look in the "slider" js code and see if there's an init() function.  in your page load, call that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the line where you compute x and y, either angle, v0, xo, or vo is null or not a number.

run a debugger and step through those lines, and check the values in place.

Comment: the only error I get is this one Uncaught error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'value' 
when it starts popping reddots

Comment: ok, so debugger, which I'm using for 1st time :D :D :D, shows that initially each parameter is 'undefined' later when I adjust some things with the sliders those parameters turn up to be with assigned values... function is 'not available'

Comment: if angle is a value from a slider control, set a default value on initialization of the control, on page load.

Comment: it didn't change anything. I'm despair :/ , really I don't think I'll find solution for it withing the next two weeks because I lack knowledge, experience and so on, for example yesterday I used a debugger for 1st time in my life, I also tryied some ideas, mine and yours and it still doesn't for. By this purpose I would like to request to anybody who has some time to contact me on PM, where I'll send the whole project and he(or she) to try to debug it. I hope it would be something pretty elementary but however I'm not able to fix it 4th day in a row, eventhough I tried so many things. Glad to

Comment: see your replays... :/
* so far I've just located where the problem is, actually where an anomaly appears but it won't be a huge surprise if it comes from somewhere else

Comment: it's also quite possible, given your admisson of your experience level, that you're assuming that those variables are global scope, when they really aren't!  Try restructuring your trajgen() function signature to this:
    function trajgen(xo, yo,angle,g,time,v0) ...and pass those variables in when you call the function, rather than assuming they're available in global scope.

Comment: I've completely switched it off by letting it as a comment and I took out angle1 and angle out in order to play with them 1 on 1 :D but yeah... NaNs, NaNs... values from previous source codes... seems like I accidentally cracked chrome but still can't fix that simple thing... :D So yeah, right now trajgen() isn't active I just modify the initialization of both because there seems to be my problem. And yeah, those vars aren't in a  function at all now. And as I said, angle does it's job perfectly but when I comes to angle1 I receive NaN and it doesn't behave like a variable, I would say...

Comment: this may sound silly...but make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces on any of those variables.  If there are, they will be interpreted as strings.  i.e. if you do:  x = " 123 " + 4;....then x will equal " 123 4", NOT "127".

Comment: worse than an array it terms of assigning new values I changed the name of angle1 to BONZAI it didn't help neither

Comment: I've just looked for spaces as you suggested and I can't find ones... hmmm

Comment: I've tried to parseInt(angle1) before assigning angle1 = (angle*Math.PI)/180. And it is still NaN, I think this is a kind of a browser bug maybe or idk, seems like angle1 locks on NaN and doesn't want to receive any other values even-though I make it do so. P.S. I have no idea how to find init function() everything except this sh.s.@1$ with the variables works without errors.

Comment: I'm knocked down, see this. Before angle1 = (angle*Math.Pi)/180 I called a typeof for angle 1 and it returns me angle 1 - number, after the line I did the same, it says number then pops out the value of angle1 - NaN... So, the type remains number but the value seems to be NaN eventhough i store it in a number. wtf... :D

Comment: My friend you was EXTREMELY RIGHT!!! I'm glad you are here, I commented the whole slider angle function and gave initial value of angle 250, the NaN disappeared and angle1 works. This means that when initially (I haven;t still moved the slide) and the value of angle is undefined, angle 1 tries to get a result form non existing value and the error occurs. Thank you, once again I'll try to fix it somehow... uff, finally.. It was so dumb :D

Comment: This illustrates one reason why it's good practice to explicitly pass in variables that will be used within the function as part of the function signature, instead of "grabbing" globals...the global variables may not be what you think they are!  Also, it helps to quickly decide if the problem is in your code, or in the inputs you're using.!!!!

Comment: Can you prompt me how to take sliders initial value before it's been moved for first time. I'm trying this: 
angle = $("#angle").slider('value');
but it doesn't work... :)

Comment: Consider this:  $(".slider").slider()
      $("#angle").slider({
        value:30,
        min:0,
        max:250,
        step:0.2,
        slide: function (event, ui){
           $( "#angres" ).html( ui.value );
           angle = ui.value;
          // trajgen();
          }
        });
$("#angle").slider('value'); <- not working

Comment: what javascript library is the slider control coming from?

Comment: jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js :D
it goes with its ui functions https://jqueryui.com/ :D

Comment: // Getter
var value = $( "#angle" ).slider( "option", "value" );

Comment: hmm, it doesn't get it on load... however, I bypassed this by making the following if(speed!=undefined&&angle!=undefined&&g!=undefined){
      vartest(angle, speed, g);
Now, initially I get angle1 NaN but after adjusting the sliders I get angle 1 = <not available> I've also removed speed, angle and gravity from globals and made them function vars...vartest() receives speed, angle and gravity but when we come back to the mada....941039 (you know what) line angle1= (angle*Math.PI)/180; angle 1 i <not available>